# How can I change select component's value from JS(TS) with using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, select, knockout.js, data-binding

I have 2 select component and they should effect each other. I've tried to solve this problem with manual but I've been astonished.

**Note 1:** selectedIndex didn't work.

**Note 2:** changing value at JS(TS) didn't update component.

Here is HTML codes:

```
        <select data-bind="options: interestRates, optionsText: 'TaksitAraligi', value: selectedInstallmentRange"></select>

        <select data-bind="options: interestRates, optionsText: 'TutarAraligi', value: selectedAmountRange"></select>
        <div class="summary-row-item-value">
                % {{interestRates()[selectedRate()].FaizOrani}}
        </div>
```

Here is TypeScript Codes

```
this.selectedInstallmentRange.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (value && value.TaksitAraligi) {
            if (_self.willChange)
                _self.interestRates().forEach(function (item: any, i: number = 0) {
                    if (item.TaksitAraligi === value.TaksitAraligi) {
                        _self.selectedRate(i);
                        _self.willChange = false;
                        _self.selectedAmountRange(_self.interestRates()[_self.selectedRate()].TutarAraligi);
                    }
                    i++;
                });
            else
                _self.willChange = true;
        }
    });

    this.selectedAmountRange.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (value && value.TutarAraligi) {
            if (_self.willChange)
                _self.interestRates().forEach(function (item: any, i: number = 0) {
                    if (item.TutarAraligi === value.TutarAraligi) {
                        _self.selectedRate(i);
                        _self.willChange = false;
                        _self.selectedInstallmentRange(_self.interestRates()[_self.selectedRate()].TaksitAraligi);
                    }
                    i++;
                });
            else
                _self.willChange = true;
        }
    });
```

I've added willChange because of infinite loop.

The second problem is solved. I've been updating data incorrectly. It shouldn't be like that;

```
_self.selectedAmountRange(_self.interestRates()[_self.selectedRate()].TutarAraligi);
```

Correct using;

```
_self.selectedAmountRange(_self.interestRates()[_self.selectedRate()]);
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "affect each other"? Can you better explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: --> Changing their datas via observables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve exactly, but you can just use `ko.computed()` to update the `options` on the dependent select.
Or if you need to update the `value` in the dependent select you could subscribe to changes on the first.

Template:

```
<div>
    <h3>Controller Select:</h3>
    <select data-bind="options: select1Options, value: select1Value"></select>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Select with options dependency:</h3>
    <p>(options updated based on controller selection)</p>
    <select data-bind="options: select2Options"></select>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>Select with value dependency:</h3>
    <p>(value updated based on controller selection)</p>
    <select data-bind="options: select3Options, value: select3Value"></select>
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    this.select1Options = ko.observableArray(['asd', 'lol', 'rofl']);
    this.select3Options = ko.observableArray(['asd', 'lol', 'rofl']);
    this.select1Value = ko.observable(null);
    this.select3Value = ko.observable(null);

    this.optionsMap = {
        'asd': [ 'asd_suboption_1', 'asd_suboption_2', 'asd_suboption_3' ],
        'lol': [ 'lol_suboption_1', 'lol_suboption_2', 'lol_suboption_3' ],
        'rofl': [ 'rofl_suboption_1', 'rofl_suboption_2', 'rofl_suboption_3' ],
    }

    this.select2Options = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.optionsMap[self.select1Value()];
    });

    this.select1Value.subscribe(function(value){
        self.select3Value(value);
    });

};

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/vqzvu4pw/9/

Comment: The select `select3Value` will not work right. If you change the select, the value can't be updated. To make it default when `select1Value` updates, but still be changeable, you should use `subscribe` instead. https://jsfiddle.net/vqzvu4pw/4/

Comment: You are right @RoyJ, my example is not really meaningful as it is. However there is a better way to do what you say, instead of using `subscribe`, it can be done with a `writable computed`: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html . Updating my answer with that.

Comment: A writable computed that ignores writes (as yours does - the write function doesn't return anything, it should be used to set things) is no improvement. I adjusted your fiddle to display the value below the select. https://jsfiddle.net/vqzvu4pw/8/

Comment: Definetely right again @RoyJ, fixed it using subscribe, as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks RoyJ & Andrea Casaccia.

This example is good for oneway binding. But second one can't update in my example. I've updated my question via your answer. Could you check it, please?

Comment: Please put some more effort in your question, explain better what you're trying to do and/or set up a fiddle. Sorry but I am not willing to understand your application to solve this problem :-)

Comment: It would be nice if you isolated the minimal code to reproduce the problem and leave apart all your application specific code.

Comment: Ahh, I've solved. The problem was that I've been updating data with it's property. It should update with complete data. I've update the code.